# How to write a bash function that invokes a grep command with constructed fileName parameter

Tags: bash, function, unix, parameters, grep

I would like to create a bash function that calls the well known `grep` command. This function should take the grep pattern as a parameter.

Now comes the tricky part. The function itself constructs the fileName parameter given to the `grep` command. Upon calling the function it seems that the `grep` command is being called but there is absolutely no output to the console. Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
specialGrep() {
    evaluatedFileNamePart=$(someOtherGrepCommandThatEvaluatesAnotherPartOfThePath)

    # take function param as pattern and use constructed filename param
    grep -i '${1}' /fixedPathPart1/"$evaluatedFileNamePart"/fixedPathPart2/*.*
}
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: The parameter won't be expanded inside singe quotes. Try it with double quotes like `grep -i "$1" ....`

Comment: Thats the solution. And here I thought the error was with the $evaluatedFileNamePart. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @user000001: Looks like that was the answer; you should probably post it that way. jimonthebarn: Please don't edit "(SOLVED)" into your title. The way to indicate that your problem is solved is to accept an answer.

Comment: Note that you should learn how to use `bash -x script` (and often, inside functions, `set -x` and `set +x`) to see what the script is doing for you.  This would help you avoid needing to ask such questions again.

Comment: @KeithThompson Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because Variable referencing is disabled by single quotes, which cause the "$" to be interpreted literally.

For example if you do:

```
var="test"
echo "$var"    # will print test
echo '$var'    # will print $var
```

For more info, read this: [Variable Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html), Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide.

Answer (score 3):

```
 grep -i "${1}" /fixedPathPart1/"$evaluatedFileNamePart"/fixedPathPart2/*.*
```